# Common Signin and Signout developed in webapi, how to integrate to my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Here is my problem: I have a common sign-in and signup pages which are developed in a web API, I want to centralize all the users of my product into a single database so that it is developed. How to integrate those centralized login service to my other products? For e.g.: If I have an application it takes login from the service project if I say sign-in it should validate the user and then redirect to the home page of my application. To do that both are no where related and they are completely two separate pages. How do I link them? Anybody help me please ....

If anyone needs detail description, it is like the signup in gmail, accessing all the Google products with same id.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What have you tried so far? Were you able to find a couple of tutorials?

Comment: Thank you thanks for the edit i didnot notice my mistake

Comment: Classic ASP and ASP.NET are two different technolgoies.

Comment: sorry paul that was by mistake

Comment: Somebody get me answer pls...

Answer (score 0):

I think the OAuth2 is a good option for you, please have a look at: [OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)